# Improving performance on a long list without a fixed height/virtualization

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a webapp that can display lists of exhibitors (amongst others) for an expo. 
When the user clicks "Exhibitors" on the nav, it will load up a page that lists all the exhibitors. They can have various configurable details and may or may not have data for those details (Booth, Videos, etc). Because of this, UX has eliminated the option of having a fixed height for the rows.

[image]
The problem is that when we load up this page, if there are 500+ exhibitors, the dom freezes until it renders them all. This can take a decent chunk of time, especially on mobile. Without a fixed row height, virtualization seems nearly impossible. Now I am looking for some ideas to improve performance without sacrificing the UX to a large degree.

What i have tried:

1. Batching the data-binding. I have broken the list into chunks and run them through a queue that wraps them anonymously and delays them to break the execution chain.
2. On demand loading. Binding and rendering only the first 50 or so, then loading and appending the next chunk when they scroll.

Any thoughts/suggestions are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of 500 elements, lazy loading is probably your best bet. If the size of your data from that request is not a lot, you can download all of your necessary data in one request (assuming this is coming from a web service) and just add to the list on demand, or you can do a request for each batch of items.

Also, when you are adding the elements to your list, make sure you are only adding them to the DOM in a single iteration, instead of adding the HTML for each individual element, which will help you reduce how many times your DOM is forced to reflow which helps immensely with performance.

So instead of:

```
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    $(container).append($('<p>new element</p>'));
}
```

You would do this:

```
html = '';
for ( i = 0; i < length; i++ ) {
    html += '<p>new element</p>';
}
$(container).append($(html));
```

-----Update------
Here is some code I have used in the past (assuming you are using jquery)

```
function contentNearBottom(container, child, threshold) {
    var total_height, current_scroll, visible_height;

    current_scroll = container.scrollTop();
    visible_height = container.height();
    total_height = child.height();

    if (threshold < 0) threshold = 0;

    //console.log('total: ' + total_height + ' threshold: ' + threshold + ' current: ' + current_scroll + ' visible: ' + visible_height);
    return ((total_height - threshold) <= (current_scroll - visible_height));
}

function lazyLoadMessages() {
    if (contentNearBottom($("div.content"), $("div.content > ul"), 2500)) {
        // load more data
    }
}
```

Somewhere in the document ready

```
$(document).on('scrollstart scrollstop', 'div.content', function(event) {
    lazyLoadMessages();
});
```

The html

```
<div class="content">
    <ul>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point on the 2nd one, i'm going to go through and optimize where i can. For the lazy loading, are you referring to something similar to my on demand loading i described above? I'm just wondering if you have another idea as to know when the data needs to be loaded.

Comment: Yeah the on demand loading. Basically, what you can do is listen to the scrolling events for the container element and determine if the user is at a certain point in the list that you would want to start loading more data to the list, and do your data retrieval and element insertions.

Comment: In case you needed it I updated my answer to include an example of how I did lazy loading with scrolling listeners. The threshold should be set to however many pixels you want to start loading more data. For myself we did 50 elements which were around 75pixels tall, so 2500 was around when only 17 elements were remaining to be scrolled on the list.